# Como alinhar 4 divs com imagem

Tags: html, imagem, div, css

Como eu faço para alinhar meus textos e imagens lado a lado como desta forma abaixo:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pesquisei e testei várias formas de alinhar e não consegui. Atualmente está assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código que eu utilizei para fazer isso é esse:

```html
<div align="center"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0334/8607/7996/files/box_60x52.png?v=1615594928"></div><div style=" text-align:center;"><h2>frete grátis</h2> Frete Grátis para todos as compras independente do valor.
</div>
<div align="center"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0334/8607/7996/files/cashback_60x52.png?v=1615594928"></div>
<div style="text-align:center;"><h2>SATISFAÇÃO GARANTIDA
</h2> Ou seu dinheiro de volta, sua satisfação é o nosso negócio.</div>


<div align="center"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0334/8607/7996/files/customer-service_60x52.png?v=1615594928"></div>
<div style="text-align:center;"><h2>SUPORTE ESPECIALIZADO
</h2> Obtenha rápido suporte através do whatsapp ou e-mail.
</div>
<div align="center"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0334/8607/7996/files/shield_60x52.png?v=1615594928"></div>
<div style="text-align:center;"><h2>COMPRA SEGURA
</h2> Seus dados são estão seguros protegidos por criptografia.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ajudar na formação, podemos incluir todos os divs em outro div (vamos chamar de "container") com o `display: flex`.

Para entender mais o `display: flex`, sugiro ler essa outra pergunta: [Estilização de Grid para galeria usando display flex](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/235779/estiliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-grid-para-galeria-usando-display-flex)

Assim como também sugeriu o @SrTecc na sua resposta, é uma boa ideia separa os estilos em `css`.  Aqui em exemplo dessa implementação:

```css
.container {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex
}

.container div {
   padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0334/8607/7996/files/box_60x52.png?v=1615594928">
        <h2>FRETE GRÁTIS</h2>
        <p>Frete Grátis para todos as compras independente do valor.</p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0334/8607/7996/files/cashback_60x52.png?v=1615594928">
        <h2>SATISFAÇÃO GARANTIDA</h2>
        <p>Ou seu dinheiro de volta, sua satisfação é o nosso negócio.</p> 
    </div>

    <div>
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0334/8607/7996/files/customer-service_60x52.png?v=1615594928">
        <h2>SUPORTE ESPECIALIZADO</h2> 
        <p>Obtenha rápido suporte através do whatsapp ou e-mail.</p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0334/8607/7996/files/shield_60x52.png?v=1615594928">
        <h2>COMPRA SEGURA</h2>
        <p>Seus dados são estão seguros protegidos por criptografia.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Erica seja bem vinda.

Seu código estava um pouco bagunçado então tomei a liberdade de arrumar ele, recomendo que utilize css para organizar as coisas em sua pagina, desse modo fica mais fácil de deixar alinhado e o código não fica tão poluído.

Esse é o código em html:

```
<div class="teste">
        
        <div class="teste2">
            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0334/8607/7996/files/box_60x52.png?v=1615594928">
            <h2>frete grátis</h2>
            <p>Frete Grátis para todos as compras independente do valor.</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="teste2">
            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0334/8607/7996/files/cashback_60x52.png?v=1615594928">
            <h2>SATISFAÇÃO GARANTIDA</h2>
            <p>Ou seu dinheiro de volta, sua satisfação é o nosso negócio.</p> 
        </div>

        <div class="teste2">
            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0334/8607/7996/files/customer-service_60x52.png?v=1615594928">
            <h2>SUPORTE ESPECIALIZADO</h2> 
            <p>Obtenha rápido suporte através do whatsapp ou e-mail.</p>
        </div>

        <div>
            <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0334/8607/7996/files/shield_60x52.png?v=1615594928">
            <h2>COMPRA SEGURA</h2>
            <p>Seus dados são estão seguros protegidos por criptografia.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Essa é a parte em css:

```
.teste{
    padding-top: 90px;
    text-align: center;
}

.teste2{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}

.teste2 p{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Coloquei os nomes de teste e teste2 pode alterar depois mas lembre-se de alterar no css também.

Imagem da pagina:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado :)